# JQuery Range Input Listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

Hey having a little trouble jquery and the hmtl5 range. I'm try to get the values as they changed but the event listener is not capturing it. Currently my code is:

HTML

```
html += '<li>Apply Credits: <input type="range"  min="0" max="'+credits+'" name="discount_credits" id="discount_credits" /> <span>'+credits+'</span></li>'
```

And the JS is:

```
$('#discount_credits').mousewheel( function() { 
        alert('it changed!'); 
        alert('new value = ' + $(this).val()); 
    });
```

I've also tried

```
$('#discount_credits').change( function() { 
            alert('it changed!'); 
            alert('new value = ' + $(this).val()); 
        });
```

Neither seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the event handler added after the range input is injected into the DOM?

Answer (score 48):

```
$('input[type=range]').on('input', function () {
    $(this).trigger('change');
});
```

This fires the `change` event on every `input` event.

Answer (score 19):

Does not seem to have any problem on HTML5 `<input type="range">` using `change`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BaEar/33/

Comment: It only updates the span value when I release the slider button, on keyup. In Google Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 using jQuery 2.0.3.

Comment: may not be big of a deal, but it also triggers when just hovering the slider with the mouse. otherwise great solution!

Comment: in Chrome, at least, attaching handler to the 'input' event gets triggered even when hovering. for the 'change' event, this is not the case. so i opted for 'change', as hovering is not considered input in my case. the hovering effect could be problematic if your handler triggers dom manipulation or ajax calls.

Answer (score 6):

I assume your span has an id: `<span id="slidernumber">...</span>`
Lets also assume that you have a few sliders, and you want to see a text change if any of them were moved:

```
<li>
Apply Credits1: 
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
name="discount_credits1" id="discount_credits" 
/>
</li>

<li>
Apply Credits2: 
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
name="discount_credits2" id="discount_credits" 
/>
</li>

<span id="slidernumber">50</span>
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[type=range]").change(function(){
    var newval=$(this).val();
    $("#slidernumber").text(newval);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MahshidZeinaly/CgQ5c/

Now lets assume that you have a few sliders, but you want to see a text change if a particular one of them were moved. (I assume it because the range input is inside li tag, and you gave it a name):

```
<li>
Apply Credits1: 
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
name="discount_credits1" id="discount_credits" 
/>
<span id="slidernumber">50</span>
</li>

<li>
Apply Credits2: 
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
name="discount_credits2" id="discount_credits" 
/>
<span id="slidernumber">50</span>
</li>
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[type=range]").change(function(){
    var newv=$(this).val();
    $(this).next().text(newv);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MahshidZeinaly/2pe7P/1/

Answer (score 4):

The on change event seems to be working correctly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zV3xD/7/

```
<input type="range"  min="0" max="100" name="discount_credits" id="discount_credits" />

<span id="newValue" value="0">0</span>

$('#discount_credits').change( function() {
    var newValue = this.value;        
    $('#newValue').html(newValue);
});​
```

Or you can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VwTu2/):

```
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(a.value)">
    <input type="range" name="a" value="50" /> =
    <output name="result">0</output>
</form>
```

Using the `output` example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output

Comment: It only updates the #newValue when I release the slider button, on keyup. In Google Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 using jQuery 2.0.3.

Comment: Hi @CarolineSchnapp - I've updated my example to show another way of approaching this issue. If it isn't sufficient, please let me know and we can figure out something that will.

Answer (score -1):

Several test and bug fixed!

```
$('input[name=form_range]').change('mousestop',function () {

});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve OPs problem (of capturing the new value while the user is still holding the mouse button pressed down): http://jsfiddle.net/zV3xD/7/