# Check if HTML input range is a certain value - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically change a page when the the input range is changed to different values? Anyway for jquery to check the value on the fly and allow me to set conditions when the range is moved to a certain value? Thanks

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="adjust" id="range"/>

if ( $('input[type="range"]').is().val(50) ) {

 alert('Value is 50');

}
```

Comment: You should check out answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473554/jquery-range-input-listener

Comment: This is exactly why you should never learn jQuery before JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Attach OnChange event handler:

```js
  $(function(){
      $("#range").change(function(){        
        if ( $(this).val() == "50")
        {
            alert('Value is 50');
        }
        $("#value").text($(this).val());
      });    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="0" value="25" max="100" name="adjust" id="range"/>

<span id="value"></span>
```